# Detect JPG Compression Rate?

Tags: image, compression, jpeg, gd

Normally when an image comes into my site I save it as jpg using an image library I wrote with the  default quality of 80%.  Now when I need to do some other operation on it (like cropping it, or even just resizing it) the image will be opened as jpg, processed, then saved back.  However, if it has been compressed before I don't want to compress it again or else every time I need to do an operation the quality will fall.

Is there a way that I can detect how much the image has already been compressed before (in comparison to a png version of it I guess) using tools in the standard GD php libraries?  I know that tools which detect where an image has been Photoshopped do so by comparing relative amounts of compression so I would think it is possible to detect the amount of compression but does anyone know how I would go about doing this calculation?  Thanks.

Comment: for what I know, you cannot get a quality rate from a jpg file

Comment: I know that it is not saved in the meta data of the file itself but maybe there is some way to calculate it

Comment: If you have the space for it, you might want to just keep the original file around (but not public) instead. Then, when you need to do some more processing, you do it on the original, so you don't have to worry about continual re-compression ruining your image quality.

Comment: @Flatness: Thank you for the idea, I was in fact doing this originally but the problem is that over time I do various operations (resize, crop, color shift, etc.) and I would have to keep a version in between , or save somewhere what operations to do from the original to get to the current and it wasn't worth it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot get quality value from JPG. Moreover, the quality value is encoder dependent. It is not a standard or anything like this. Some programs have only (low, medium, high), in some 20 might be better than 90.

Secondly, JPG simply will lose quality in each cosnequent encoding, even if you save it as best quality every time. Sad truth of life :) The only operations that do not worse the quality are flips and rotations (and crops, if they are aligned to JPEG block size).

Rule of the thumb: Encode it **every time at the same quality value.** Example: If you save it once at let's say 60, then there is no gain if you save it at 80 next time. Just bigger file size.

Also, try to reduce the number of such re-encodings and perform each manipulation on the original , if you have enough storage available.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store the image's quality in a database so you can know if it has already been compressed or not.

Comment: Even then if he resizes the image, the quality will drop. Saving that is meaningless.
But, good thought, therefore there is a +1.

Comment: @RokKralj I suggest saving so that he does not compress it more than once. He could deteriorate the image even more..

Comment: You do not understand everything. There is no "compress", it is just save at quality value. If you mean that he saves it once at 80, then remember that, so he can save it at 100 the next time...? That would only increase file size at no quality gain. 80 -> 80 -> 80 is correct saving.

Comment: No, I mean he can store the 80 value, and do something like if($stored_quality > 80){ //perform operations AND compress} else {// perform only operations}. This way, the only loss of quality would be from the operations and he won't drop the image's quality each time. Of course increasing the quality would not be an option.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid compressing the image multiple times you could simply compare the  file size of the resize with the original.

- If the file size is noticeably larger then you've increased the rate, so don't use it.
- If it's noticeably lower than it has compressed, so use it.

Also, as recompressing a file with the same rate only shaves a small amount off of the file size, if you use round numbers for your rates (60%, 70%, 80% etc.) you could ascertain the rate if the resize's file size is very similar to the original's.

For example, compressing a `1,844 KB` file at:
- `90%` = `2,115 KB`. The size increased, so I won't use it.
- `80%` = `1,843 KB`. This is almost identical to the original's file size so I can assume that the original has an `80%` rate.
- `70%` = `1,567 KB`. This has compressed, so I'll use it.

Finally, if you're only concerned with the rates of images that you've compressed yourself, then you could use PHP to save the rate you use in the file's metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You actually **can** detect the quality at which a JPG image has been compressed, with some degree of certainty, if it has been encoded only once.

You can do it with a command-line tool called `identify`, which is part of Imagemagick (which is also available as a PHP library, see below). You can run, for example:

`identify -verbose 11397254.jpg`

and you will get an output like this:

```
Image: 11397254.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 600x833+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 499800
    Red:
      min: 7 (0.027451)
      max: 251 (0.984314)
      mean: 205.535 (0.80602)
      standard deviation: 40.8098 (0.160038)
      kurtosis: 7.3041
      skewness: -2.81763
      entropy: 0.627683
    Green:
      min: 4 (0.0156863)
      max: 237 (0.929412)
      mean: 200.186 (0.785044)
      standard deviation: 45.9241 (0.180095)
      kurtosis: 3.86968
      skewness: -2.25667
      entropy: 0.6339
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 241 (0.945098)
      mean: 191.701 (0.75177)
      standard deviation: 54.6716 (0.214399)
      kurtosis: 1.22795
      skewness: -1.70134
      entropy: 0.664107
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 251 (0.984314)
      mean: 199.141 (0.780945)
      standard deviation: 47.4814 (0.186202)
      kurtosis: 3.61004
      skewness: -2.23079
      entropy: 0.641896
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: JPEG
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 600x833+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 100
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2020-10-28T09:13:49+01:00
    date:modify: 2020-10-28T09:13:45+01:00
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
    signature: 7b5dc010915e4ae8b89891f7259a6f22efc69a31e5244403db580b70adc2ee94
  Artifacts:
    filename: 11397254.jpg
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 147KB
  Number pixels: 500K
  Pixels per second: 49.98MB
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.010
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Where the important lines are:

```
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 100
```

If quality is 100, it means that the image hasn't been compressed at all.

I tested this tool against GIMP JPG compression, and it was very accurate in detecting the percentage of compression I used on images.

In PHP, there's a function in the ImageMagick library:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.identifyimage.php

It seems to be a porting of the same tool, so you could check that.

Comment: JPG quality 100 still doesn't mean lossless compression. (And of course it doesn't mean that the image hasn't been compressed; it's still significantly smaller than the equivalent PNG file, let alone BMP.) Apart from that: yes, it is possible to detect the image quality (the `identify` utility, or an image editor like IrfanView, can display it); but it still isn't clear how to do this programmatically.

Comment: So: ImageMagic `identify` utility (or other software which display the image quality) just estimate the quality by analyzing the image itself. There doesn't appear to be an objective definition of JPG image quality. See https://superuser.com/questions/62730 . (This can be seen from images in that question, for which IrfanView reports different, but roughly equivalent, quality than ImageMagic. If image has quality around 100%, but has bad artifacts, it can also mean that the image has been re-encoded at 100% including the JPG artifacts.)